# Crop an image with preset aspect ratio and width/height and save

Tags: java, android, image, crop

I've built a camera app which let me take pictures but I want to save it with a specific (preset) width/height and aspect ratio.

Example:

[image: Example crop image with margins]

- Red: old picture (source)
- Green: new picture
- Between Red and Green: margins

I've tried the following (without luck):

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(editPhotoFile.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
    Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, margin, margin, bitmap.getWidth() - margin, bitmap.getHeight() - margin);
```

With the margins I've tried to accomplish to cut a specific amount of pixels on the left (first margin) and top (second margin) and the same on the total width and height. Not working.

There are also some libraries on Github available, but they all let me select an image and edit it - I don't need the manual editing, I want to have preset margins to crop.

- [Library 'Yalantis / uCrop'](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop)
- [Library 'ArthurHub / Android-Image-Cropper'](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/sample/MainFragment.java)

Also, the possible solutions here on Stack Overflow and just by Googling or finding tutorials don't give me any luck.
Search queries:

> java android crop image
>
> java android crop image tutorial

Who can help me?

Comment: so you do not want the user to edit the image croping..portion ?

Comment: Nope. I want to crop the image myself, so the image has the same ratio on each device. Some devices have a 3:4 sensor, others 9:16 or 16:9, and so on. That's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting there as well. Struggled for weeks, but my brain got clearified: everything was doing OK, but I wasn't saving the picture/image to the device.

Margins are working.

Will update/edit this post tomorrow with the solution I've found.

**Update:**

```
    // get String with path to file from other activity and make new File of it
    File editPhotoFile = new File(globalFileString);
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

    // crop the bitmap with new margins: bitmap, left, top, width, height
    Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, marginLeft, marginTop, bitmapHeight, bitmapWidth);

    // save bitmap to new file
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    File mediaFile;
    try {
        mediaFile = new File(globalFileString);
        out = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
        croppedBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```